# How do you move images and text onto a page in a slide motion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an idea for a banner on my new site but I cant figure out how to do it or where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what im thinking:

I have three circle images and some text that i want to slide onto the screen from the left to right using an animation.

The first animation would be for some text and a circle to slide in from the left hand side of the screen.

The second animation would be for the text that is currently on the screen to slide right and fade away just before it hits the already existing circle image and for new text to slide in at the same time. Along with the text a second smaller circle would slide in and stop on top of the old bigger one.

The third animation would just be a repeat of the second animation but with a smaller circle image.

Example:
[image]

Again any help would be great and sorry for any previous confusion.

Many thanks Crackruckles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna look at jquery ui toggle().
Simple example here https://jquerytipsntricks.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/slide-toggle-from-right-to-left-and-left-to-right-using-jquery-ui/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar one, you can just do some work around to fit your taste.

[Sample](http://codepen.io/qtgye/pen/Didot)

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     @keyframes toright {
  from {
    right: 600px;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
}

.container  div {
  display: inline-block;  
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:5px;
}

.one {
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: 1s toright ease;
}
.two { 
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: 1.3s toright ease;
}
.three {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  animation: 1.5s toright ease;
}
```

Comment: I have the three circles already and i know where to place them i just need to figure out how to do the animation really, sorry if i was clear on tha, but thanks anyway.